# sql/coldfusion delete duplicate rows

Tags: sql, coldfusion

Here is my table

```
Display          UPC
0                0553406259120
0                0753406259120
1                0753406259120
1                0453406259120
```

If you notice, row 2 and 3 have the same UPC. I would like to delete all rows that have display = 0 and duplicate upc. So in my table I want to delete row 2 only. Here is my coldfusion code so far that doesn't work. Please advice.

```
<cfquery name="GetData" datasource="#Application.ds#" dbtype="ODBC" username="#Application.UserName#" password="#Application.Password#">
DELETE UPC
FROM products
WHERE DISPLAY = 0
GROUP BY UPC  
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
</cfquery>
```

Comment: What database & database version?

Comment: So you want to delete the row where `Display = '0'` and the UPC is duplicated across `Display` values?

Comment: Also can there be multiple UPC values where `Display = 1`?

Comment: @dmitrymar - What about the other questions?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to delete all rows where `UPC` is the same, but `Display` is different:

```
DELETE FROM Products as a
WHERE display = 0
AND EXISTS (SELECT '1'
            FROM Products as b
            WHERE b.display <> 0
            AND b.upc = a.upc)
```

This should work on all RDBMSs, and will remove all rows where `UPC` is the same, but with a different `Display` codes.

Comment: Just curious, does it work in mySQL? I seem to remember some versions not supporting aliases with DELETE.

Comment: You can delete and/or update using an alias for a table in MSSQL.

Comment: @Mark - *Edit* Yep, but I meant mySQL :) I could be wrong though. I do not use mySQL nearly as much as MS SQL. *Edit*: dmitrymar did not mention his db type. But from his question history, I am guessing it might be mySQL.

Comment: rats... missed that in your question. Need to read more carefully.

Comment: @X-Zero - Yep, I understood that. I was not knocking your suggestion. (It is what I would have suggested too.) I only raised the question because I a) suspected the OP *might* be using mySQL and b) thought you might be a heavy mySQL user and know the magic syntax. (I am only an occasional user myself :)

Comment: @Leigh - I've used mySQL once, years ago, and not since.  Things I take for granted on DB2 (and are available on most other RDBMSs) trip me up on occasion, when I attempt to answer some of these questions.  Like CTEs.

Comment: @X-Zero - Yeah, same here - just with an MS SQL slant instead of DB2. But I am still not sure which db type dmitrymar is using. Guess we will wait and see.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Products
WHERE DISPLAY = 0 
AND UPC in (SELECT UPC
            FROM Products
            GROUP BY UPC
            HAVING COUNT(UPC)>1)
```

Comment: While this should delete everything where there is more than one instance of `UPC`, the OP had a specific, additional criteria for when those rows could be deleted.  Could you add the missing `WHERE` clause, please?