# sql/coldfusion display duplicated row

Tags: sql, coldfusion

Given the table below I would like implement this logic into my query: If 2 UPC's are the same then display the row that has highest PRODUCTID value. So in my table it would be row 2.

```
PRODUCTID        UPC
100              01434
101              01434
102              05877
```

Here is my code which I need help with

```
<cfquery name="GetData" datasource="#Application.ds#" dbtype="ODBC" username="#Application.UserName#" password="#Application.Password#">
Select PRODUCTID, UPC 
FROM Products
Where ...
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Do you need to display other columns from the table - in addition to `UPC` and `ProductID`? (Also, please update the tags to indicate which db type you are using)

Comment: .. and is this related to your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289032/sql-coldfusion-delete-duplicate-rows ie Are you ultimately trying to delete the duplicate rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(PRODUCTID) AS PRODUCTID, UPC
FROM Products
GROUP BY UPC
HAVING COUNT(UPC) > 1
```

Comment: I don't see why you have the HAVING on there, now you've removed ProductID 102 from the results.

Comment: I used Nick's code but slightly modified to SELECT MAX(PRODUCTID) AS PID

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this query...

```
SELECT MAX(ProductId) as Id, Upc 
FROM Products
GROUP BY Upc
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=DuplicateRows

Comment: Since the ProductID is a unique key, the query will not work if you group by it

Comment: Updated accordingly... Thanks for the heads up!